# android - findViewById using a String

Tags: java, android, string, imagebutton, findviewbyid

I have many many ImageButtons,

and i want to use something to shortcut the code.

Like use findViewById method with a String value same `findViewById("R.id.btn_name")`,

or get button by tag,

or something like this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("btn_name", "id", this.getPackageName());
```

where `this` refers to the `context`/`activity`. Then use it as follows:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
```

Comment: what's names of `btn_name` and `id` in `xml file`

Comment: `"id"` remains as `"id"`, `"btn_name"` is the from your question, you said `findViewById("R.id.btn_name")`. Its is the string of the id variable.

Comment: so `btn_name` and `id` = Id ?